# Преувеличить/приувеличить

Tags: орфография, глаголы, приставка

Корректно ли таки я думаю или нет?

`Я преувеличил доходы компании.` (Я сказал, что доходы были большие, но на самом деле они были гораздо-таки меньше.)

`Я приувеличил доходы компании.` (Я доходы компании, маленькие, смог-таки сделать больше, чем они были.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В качестве рабочего материала к обсуждаемому вопросу.**

**Скворцов, Лев Иванович.
Большой толковый словарь правильной русской речи** : 8 000 слов и выражений / Л. И. Скворцов. - Москва ; Санкт-Петербург : Диля, 2007. - 1135 с.; 27 см.; ISBN 978-5-88503-463-0 (В пер.):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

*Я **преувеличил** доходы компании.*

*Я **отчасти увеличил** доходы компании.*  (Нет слова приувеличить.)

**ПРЕУВЕЛИЧИТЬ,** -чу, -чишь; преувеличенный; -чен, -а, -о; св. (что). Представить что-л. в больших по сравнению с действительностью размерах; придать чему-л. чрезмерно важное значение. П. размеры бедствия. П. чьи-л. заслуги. <Преувеличивать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Я не преувеличиваю: вы гений! Охотники любят п. в своих рассказах. Преувеличиваться, -ается; страд. Преувеличение (см.).

**[Статья по теме: преувеличить или приувеличить.](https://znanieinfo.ru/orfografiya/preuvelichit-ili-priuvelichit.html)**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1. Основным орфографическим словарем является **словарь РАН,**  в который постоянно вносятся текущие изменения : Научно-информационный «Орфографический академический ресурс АКАДЕМОС» Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН.

Поэтому  в спорных вопросах **нельзя ориентироваться** на другие источники, в том числе на «Большой толковый словарь правильной русской речи» Скворцова Л.И. (2007 год),  так как информация может измениться.

2. Можно сделать вывод, что раньше **допускалась** форма «приувеличить», но теперь она считается некорректной.  Интересен вопрос: почему изменилось решение? Объяснений нет, то можно **предположить** следующее.
3. **Приставка *ПРЕ***  обозначает превосходную степень или, другими словами, **превышение** величины. Мы можем превысить ее в большей или меньшей степени, но в любом случае это будет обозначено приставкой ***ПРЕ***. Поэтому мы выбираем только одну форму: ***преувеличить***.

**Приставка *ПРИ*** обозначает приближение в какой либо величине, поэтому можно приуменьшить (уменьшить немного) и преуменьшить (уменьшить значительно).  В этом случае нужны две формы: ***приуменьшить и преуменьшить.***

Comment: Я, вообще-то, по аналогии с *преуменьшить – приуменьшить* (из РАН) придумал!

Comment: Наверх взгланите-ка.

Comment: Sharon, голосую за ваш ответ. Интересно отметить, что с "преумножить/приумножить"   наоборот – остался только "пр**и**умножить", так как значения у них практически не отличаются.

Comment: Спасибо!  Да, интересно.  У приставки ПРИ есть еще значение НЕПОЛНОГО действия (как бы приближение к полному действию).  Возможно, в  слове "приумножить" имеется в виду такое приближение.

Comment: [Вот небольшая статейка на эту тему](https://aif.ru/society/education/preumnozhit_ili_priumnozhit_kak_pravilno), может, видели-читали, там и про "при(е)уменьшить" есть.

Comment: Спасибо, прочитала, не согласна))  За уши у них притянута приставка ПРИ.   Например: умножить капитал в 2 раза – это увеличить капитал в 2 раза,  Или такой вариант: значительно увеличить капитал. А приумножить капитал – это небольшое увеличение, как мне думается.  Или как?

Comment: Я согласен с этим: "Письменное различение глаголов с приставками пре- и при- в данном случае бессмысленно — семантическое разграничение их затруднительно в силу лексического значения производящего глагола умножить, уже обозначающего многократное увеличение". Словари писали одно и то же на два глагола. А если небольшое увеличение, то тогда как раз "пр**и**увеличить" подходит :)) Короче, заморочки.